# Changing a table view cell in a standard view controller'

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a TableView and in it I have a cell that I need to change the background color of. I've tried searching for an answer to change the background color of the cell but the problem is that every answer I find has to do with an override tableview function, which will not work because I do not have a tableviewcontroller, rather it is a normal view controller with a UITableView embedded. [image]

How can I simply change the background color of the cell?

Comment: Overriding a tableView function is correct.  Control drag from the tableView to the yellow button and set the delegate and datasource to the viewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First give your table view cell an Identifier via the storyboard like this:

[image]

Then additionally to [vadian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41350553/5327882) access your cell in the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` DataSource method like this and update the color, in the example I put the method in an extension:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

    return cell
  }

}
```

Also don't forget to add the `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` method to conform the UITableViewDataSource protocol

Like rMickeyD mentioned in the comments, don't forget to set your table view as `dataSource` and `delegate` with `Ctrl + Drag` from the table view to the view controller like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter if it's an implicit or explicit table view.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set the property `backgroundColor` of the cell:

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
```