# didSelectRowAt Swift 3 Not Called even after delegate and dataSource are set

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitableview

This question seems to have been asked many times on StackOverflow, but after searching for hours, I still haven't found the solution to my issue.

I have a table view in **SecondViewController.swift** and I did make it **delegate** and **dataSource** **SecondViewController.swift**, but the **didSelectRowAt** method is still not fired when a table cell is clicked. I am trying to apply a segue to another view controller, but the **didSelectRowAt** method isn't working itself.

I have selected **Single Selection** in my storyboard in the table view properties, and I have made sure that **user interaction** is enabled for the table view and the prototype cell.

For the **SecondViewController.swift** below, please assume that allEvents are populated into the allEvents array. I was able to successfully populate them and display them in the table. The only problem is clicking on the row to perform a segue. Also, please ignore the awkward indentation below.

**SecondViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,    UITableViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

  var allEvents: Array<JSON> = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    //self.tabBarItem.image = myTabImage
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.25, green:0.25, blue:0.25, alpha:1.0)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.white

    //ASSUME ALL EVENTS ARE POPULATED INTO allEvents

  }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// MARK: Tableview Datasource
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return allEvents.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 150
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("SEGUE")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "oneSegue", sender: allEvents[indexPath.row])
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventViewTableCell", for: indexPath) as! EventViewTableCell        

    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   // let detailController = segue.destination as! EventDetailsController


}
}
```

I have been on this for hours and still have not found out the problem. I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Does "SEGUE" print out in the console window?

Comment: It doesn't print in the console window.

Comment: I really don't see anything in your code that would indicate that type of issue. Check the frame of your tableView - make sure you don't have any other transparent views stacked on top that would prevent touch events from being handled on the tableView.

Comment: Don't forget to set your table view as dataSource and delegate in the Interface Builder like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41350632/5327882

Comment: In my storyboard, there is tableView with the prototype cell inside it, and a contentView inside the prototype cell. The contentView comes with the prototype cell by default. Also, the dataSource and delegate are already set in the Interface Builder.

Comment: Have you tried the solution found here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906854/how-can-i-make-my-cells-selectable-when-there-is-an-uiview-below-the-uicollectio

Answer (score 11):

You may want to check your tableview again, do choose single selection.

I'm assuming you are selecting **No Selection** as the picture bellow

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I have selected Single Selection as I mentioned in the original post, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: How about enabling user interaction for the view?

Comment: Yes, I've done that also, as mentioned in my original post, but still doesn't work...

Comment: This one was it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a Controller within a TabBarController.

What fixed it for me was this:

Disable the User Interaction for the **Content view**

[image]

My guess is that it was becoming the responder so it removed the event from the TableView

Note: Since the viewDidLoad assignments to `delegate` and `dataSource` became redundant after setting it up in the StoryBoard, I removed them, although leaving them does no harm.

Answer (score 0):

If you do nothing else than calling the segue in `didSelectRowAt` remove the entire method and connect the segue in Interface Builder to the table view cell (rather than to the controller). The `sender` parameter will contain the reference to the selected table view cell.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect when you collected and populated your `allEvents` array did you collect any touch events in there ?
or have you used UIGestureRecognizer in this or it's super view ?
If you have intercepted any touch event to populate your array or any other purpose comment it out and test it with a simple preloaded array like :

```
let dataSource = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

let me know if this is not your case so I can find another solution.